# Why is my photo corrupt in Camera RAW when it shows fine in-camera and in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, data-corruption, adobe-camera-raw

Here is how I see it in the back of the camera and also in photoshop preview:

[image]

But when I double click on it to open it in Camera RAW, here is how it is:

[image]

What is going on? What has happened?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think the camera preview and PS preview are taken from a small JPG file that's part of the larger NEF. I can't really comment of the actual problem (other than it looking like it's an electronics issue- duh) but this might explain why the previews are fine and the NEF is corrupted. Are there any others that have the same issue?

Comment: @BobT Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @BobT "but I think [...]". You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I will return this card I bought yesterday, it is a **"SanDisk Extreme Pro 160MB/s UDMA 7 32GB"**  card.  Because I disconnected it and connected the card again and opened the image and this time for a second or two until it was getting processed it still showed those lines but then it changes to fine and normal looking . 
I suspected it is an issue with the card?

Comment: You should edit this into the question rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, I don't think so. It might be a comment to another answer, but it "It's due to a corrupt card" is an answer, not a question.

Comment: See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted